# Android: Two or more threads? (Program is working)

Tags: android, multithreading

I have created a sample/demo/test program in Android that runs quite nicely, if you see below you will see I have created a thread. Now I want to create another thread to work with another handler... since I cannot have two run() methods... how do I do this?

This is my (working - no errors) program:

```
package com.ryan1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity implements Runnable{

int level = 0;
int seconds_running=0;

TextView the_seconds,the_level;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    the_seconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_seconds);
    the_level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_level);

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        thread2.start();
}

public void run() {

    while(seconds_running<500)
    {
        if(seconds_running %5 ==0){level++;}     

             try {
                 handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                 int a = 1000 - (level*100);
                 if(a<=100){a=25;}
                Thread.sleep(a);
                System.out.println("R "+Thread.currentThread());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

        }



private Handler handler = new Handler() {

                @Override

                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    seconds_running++;
                    int a = 1000 - (level*100);
                    the_seconds.setText(" "+seconds_running);
                    the_level.setText(level+" "+a);
                }

        };



}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use anonymous class like this.

```
    Thread thread2 = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // code here with your new handler
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

make two inner classes that extends Thread.

create an object for both the classes and call start on those objects.

Comment: I am kind of new to Android/Java, can you give me some samply code of what you wrote please?

Answer (score 1):

You are suggesting that you want two runnables, yet you only have one runnable defined, which is your 'main' class.  So what you need to do is make two different runnables, so that each can have their own code that can be run.

I would make two new classes, lets say, Runnable1 and Runnable2.  I would have both of them implement the runnable interface.  Each one of them can then contain different code to run in a separate thread.

Finally, I would change your thread creation/start code to look like this:

```
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable1());
  Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable2());
  thread.start();
  thread2.start();
```

Comment: I am kind of new to Android/Java, do you mean inner classes or normal classes and then extend them? (I think the other poster below means the same thing)

Comment: You can do either one.  There are going to be many ways to do most things.  When I made my answer, I was mostly suggesting making two new top-level classes (not inner classes), although both ways would work just fine.  I imagine for a beginner it would be easier to start with just top level classes for now.